# empty result from mysql with “\” and “-” in query

Tags: php, mysql

i have SQL query  :

```
SELECT count(art),art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer 
FROM goods 
WHERE art_manufacturer = 'ГКБ-44/150'
```

when i using phpMyAdmin, result of query is:

```
1, 950000258, ГКБ-44/150, Интерскол
```

my php file contain:

```
$art="ГКБ-44/150";\\debug
$query = "SELECT art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer FROM goods WHERE art_manufacturer = '".$art."'"; 
$sql = mysql_query($query); 
while ($recResult = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) 
{ \*do somting*\ }
```

where is my mistake? why the result of query in php is empty?

my solution
i had `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");` in my code
when i start use mysqli i commented `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");`
mistakenly i thought mysqli is solution, after i discommented `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");` i got problem again.

So what's happend?

my PHP file in UTF-8 and when i use `mysql_query("SET NAMES cp1251");` i had `SELECT art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer FROM goods WHERE art_manufacturer = "Р“РљР‘-44/150";` query to mysql DB

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

It's empty because these are specially reserved characters interpreted by PHP/SQL. I would suggest you take a look at parameterised queries or PDO, they will escape strings for you as part of their function.

EDIT: Also it could be that the encoding of your server doesn't accept Unicode characters. I would ensure your site is using UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using `mysql_*` functions they are deprecated for a long time.

Use mysqli or PDO and bind parameters to the  query not concatenate the query string with some not prepared php variables.

So just to help you pass over the issue this time you can:

```
$query = "SELECT art,art_manufacturer,group_manufacturer 
    FROM goods 
    WHERE art_manufacturer = '".mysql_real_escape_string($art)."'";
```